# Yocto Poky distro electron installation

Tags: files, yocto

I am a newbie in the Yocto community and not sure which forum would be the best for my question. In case there a better place for it, please inform me!

A new project came to my mind to create embedded OS that runs electron (nodejs environment in chromium) application. Electron is prebuilt and only downloaded when install from `npm`. All required shared libraries are installed on the system - verified with `ldd` run on the electron **electron** executable. However, when execute the file, the system reports that such file does not exists `/node_modules/electron/dist/electron`:

```
No such file or directory
```

Here is a result of `file`:

```
./node_modules/electron/dist/electron: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /libb64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=1440e984251533657f15Sfbe7e3e0942cSadfbbse, not stripped
```

From what I have read, the electron binary is built on Ubuntu 18.04. There are [guidelines](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/development/build-instructions-gn) on how to build it from scratch. But I couldn't get the `gclient` running.

The `bitbake` recipe is `core-image-sato` which has all required `x11` libraries and runs `x11` GUI.

Output of `uname` on my system:

```
$ uname -a
Linux intel-corei7-64 5.4.96-intel-pk-standard #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jan 19 68:46:31 UTC 20621 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Ouput of `ls -l /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 2 root root 10 Mar 9 2018 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> ld-2.32.so
```

Ouput of `file /lib64/ld-2.32.so`:

```
No such file or directory
```

However, `/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` is linked to `/lib/ld-2.32.so` and `/lib/ld-2.32.so` presents on the system. Why then the interpreter for the electron binary is set to the one in `/lib64`?

After deleting the `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` and creating the link to `/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`, **electron** run successfuly.

Can anyone suggest what could be have been configured or installed the wrong way (that `file` reports wrong interpreter)? Also, I am ready to provide more information for whatever is needed to identify the problem.

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.

Comment: Are you on a 64bit, x86-64 system? What is the output of `uname -a`?

Comment: @terdon it is 64bits. Here is the result of `uname -a`: Linux intel-corei7-64 5.4.96-intel-pk-standard #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jan 19 68:46:31 UTC 20621 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: And what is the output of `ls -l /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`? That seems to be what your executable requires based on what I can read in your image (this is why having text is helpful). Please [edit] your question and include this.

Comment: @terdon added the output to the question

Comment: Is `/lib64/ld-2.32.so` available?

Comment: @Kusalananda edited the post - `No such file or directory`

Comment: Found out that `/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` presents on the system